# CSS calc - with nest

Tags: css, calc

I'd like to do a simple nested calculation: subtracting one number from another (both pixel values), then multiplying the result by 2. This isn't working for me:

```
.sample {
     width: calc(2 * (410-300)px);
}
```

The result will be a pixel width.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`calc` requires +/-operators always be spaced apart. In addition, I needed to add  units on the subtracted integers.

```
.sample {
  width: calc(2 * (410px - 300px));
}
```

An alternative (slightly longer but with less adding of units), which a commenter smartly pointed out:

```
.sample {
  width: calc(2 * (410 - 300) * 1px);
}
```

via [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage.
>   The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

```css
.el {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(2 * (410px - 300px));  
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

Comment: Or just `width: calc(2 * (410 - 300) * 1px);`

Comment: @Oriol, that's a good alternative. I'm going to add it to the answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks much!

Comment: @jdscomms Can you accept my answer if you're okay with it?

Comment: What about `width: calc((410 - 300) * 2px);`?